# React - Link con url con parámetros

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objeto, reactstrap

Este código con reactjs devuelve los datos de una API y los itera, lo que intento hacer sin éxito es generar un link dinámico por cada link del tipo "diets/id".
Por ejemplo "diets/11"..."diets/12", ...

Tengo este código, me falla la parte de concatenar la URL con el ID

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ListItems extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items : [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://api-diets.local/api/diets/user/2')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json.data);
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded:true,
                    items: json.data,
                })
            });
    }

    render() {

        var {isLoaded, items} = this.state;

        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        else {

            var divStyle = {
                color: 'red',
                WebkitTransition: 'all', // note the capital 'W' here
                msTransition: 'all' // 'ms' is the only lowercase vendor prefix
            };

            return (

                <div style={divStyle}>
                    <ul>
                        {items.map(item => (
                            <li key={item.id}>
                                Id : {item.id} -  Name : {item.name}
                                <a href="diets/" + {item.id} >Ver </a>
                            </li>
                        ))
                        }
                    </ul>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

En concreto la parte que no me funciona es esta , donde intento concatenar "diets/" con el ID

```
<a href="diets/" + {item.id} >Ver </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra opción, más usada con el uso de ES6, es interpolar [usando backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings#Interpolaci%C3%B3n_de_expresiones)(**`**)

```
<a href={`diets/${item.id}`}>Ver </a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias muy amable. Funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

La concatenación tiene que ser así

```
<a href ={"diets/" + item.id}>link</a>
```